# Xamarin forms increase build and deploy speed?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

VS2017 -> New project -> C# -> Cross Platform -> Mobile App (Xamarin forms)

Clean, build project, and try to run Andriod application ->

Get error -> FastDevDirectoryCreationFailed -> Deployment Failed

I know I can resolve this by right clicking on the Android project and unchecking 'Use Fast deployment' from the Android options...but what if I want to use fast deployment? Seems to take forever to rebuild and deploy my project.

Is there any other way to increase build and deploy speed?

Ta
J

Answer (score 1):

**You could speed up by configuring your project.** You could check the configurations in Debug Builds and Release builds.

1. Enable Fast Deployment

Without Fast Deployment, Xamarin.Android has to build an APK every time there’s change in your project, regardless of size or scope.

2. UnCheck Multi-Dex

Enable Multi-Dex should be unchecked: unless your app fails to build without it.

3. Uncheck these Release-only Settings

Using AOT, Linking, or a Code Shrinker for Debug configurations is not that helpful. They will slow down your Debug builds with no real benefit.

For more details, you could check the link below. Some other tricks would be helpful too.https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/optimize-xamarin-android-builds/

**Link SDKs and Frameworks**

You could try to utilize the Linker for Release Configuration builds.

On Android Build Settings, generally, we could use Shared Mono Runtime and Fast Assembly Deployment like deploy assemblies to a directory on the device instead of bundling them in the APK. Link SDK assemblies only would reduce the time as well.

The more detailed information about speed-up the build time you could find here. https://github.com/brminnick/ImproveXamarinBuildTimes

Answer (score -1):

Use terminal commands for faster on Xamarin. You can use this documentation for Xamarin forms
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/building-apps/build-process

this will take approx half time than the usual timing.